# How can I prove that $|A| + |B| = |A\cup B| + |A\cap B|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $A$ and $B$ are sets then $|A| + |B| = |A\cup B| + |A\cap B|$.

Comment: @julien: you're correct, too!

Comment: Two of the three answers so far assume implicitly that $A,B$ are finite (by using $-$), which is not assumed here. Only Andrew's answer really gets the point.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: for disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$.

Now, $A \cup B = A \cup ( B \setminus A )$  (notice that the two are disjoint), and $B = ( B \setminus A ) \cup ( B \cap A )$.

Answer (score 4):

You can also view this formula as $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$ which might make the reasoning for this clearer. Basically, the cardinality of the union is the sum of the cardinality of each set, but elements in both sets (the cardinality of the intersection) are double-counted. So subtracting $|A \cap B|$ gives you the actual cardinality of the union.

Comment: That makes sense to me but how would i do a formal proof?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to prove that $|A\cup B|-|A|=|B|-|A\cap B|$.

What is the relation between the sets $(A\cup B)\setminus A$ and $B\setminus(A\cap B)$?

Comment: isnt the two sets same i.e B-A?

Comment: Yes they are the same, then, you can conclude the equality of their cardinality.